# What does 'terms' mean in the context?

Tags: vocabulary

> We request that you read the **terms** and conditions carefully before
>   signing.
>
> __ Martin Hewings, Advanced Grammar in Use

The two words, *terms* and *condition*s, seem to be similar and it gives me the impression that synonyms are reiterated. What does *terms* mean in the context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Terms** are the binding conditions of the contract that both parties must adhere to.  **Conditions** are criteria that must be met in order for the contract to be binding.

An example would be a signed lease contract with one term allowing you to lease an apartment for 12 months and another term that you pay $650 per month.  A condition might be that you pass a credit check before the contract becomes binding.

Another example is when purchasing a house, in which the terms include the amount you pay and transfer of ownership to you.  A typical condition would be that you qualify for financing.

Comment: I realize that there may be regional differences in terminology, but I've alrways heard what you're describing as "conditions" called "contingencies".

Answer (score 1):

In layman's terms (no pun intended), "terms and conditions" are the binding provisions of a contract. Your sentence is equivalent to the following:

> We ask that you read all the binding provisions of this contract carefully before you agree to them by signing.

There may be a more technical legal definition of "terms and conditions", but you'd have to consult a lawyer...